# How to force TextView to use as much space as possible on the first line

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with creating a chat layout.

**How can I force TextView's text to fill up the entire area?** 
Even if the string is continuous, sometimes text goes to the next line.

[image: Problem]

XML with TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/message_my_shape"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Hey mate,how youre doing?"
    android:textColor="#fcc7d3"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

UPD:
You don't quite get me, guys. Padding should be there and I don't want a single line, please see the new screenshots with layout boundaries shown to see what I'm talking about.
Question is still the same, why text in TextView doesn't fill all available space (sometimes)?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove the padding you have on the TextView.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Unfortunately, This wouldn't work.Please see an updated post

Comment: I still have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Just answered my own question. Ta

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution.

For API 23 and higher add to your TextView:

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
```

For API < 23 remove hidden `&nbsp;` from you text dynamically (android adds them automatically).

Answer (score -1):

This reason why this happens is that you didn't specify that your `TextView` only has one line.

From the documentation:

> **android:maxLines**
>
> Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall. When used on an
>   editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be combined with
>   the textMultiLine flag for the maxLines attribute to apply.

So if you want to always have a single line of text use:

```
android:maxLines=1
```

---

Anything this to your code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/message_my_shape"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Hey mate,how youre doing?"
    android:textColor="#fcc7d3"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:maxLines=1
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Unfortunately, This is not the case, It needs to be multiline. Please see an updated post